# ajax post not posting all form values to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a from that I add it with a script Latitude & latitude ,and pass it to a textInput and then I post it to the controller with ajax, how ever the value in this "dynamic" text input is always null at the controller side and has value when I inspect the element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetLocation() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;
        var labelvar = document.getElementById('sys');

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                console.log("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude); //Ok.

                labelvar.innerHTML = latitude + longitude; //Ok.

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Create',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#RestoForm').serialize(),
                    datetype: "html",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#RestoForm').html(data);
                    }
                });

                error: function e(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

```csharp
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var viewModel = new LectureFormViewModel
    {
        Genres = _context.Genres.ToList(),
    };
    return View("TGigform", viewModel);
}

[Authorize, HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(LectureFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.Genres = _context.Genres.ToList();
            return View("TGigform", viewModel);
        }

        var lectureGig = new LectureGig
        {
            LatLong = viewModel.LatLong,
        };
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "TMaps", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "RestoForm"}))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LatLong)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LatLong, new {@id = "sys"})
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="GetLocation()" value="Finish"/>
}
```

All other values except `labelvar` are fine and get to the controller.
thanks

Comment: Show your controller method signature (what are you binding to?)

Comment: Assuming `labelvar` is an `input` you need to set its `value`, not the `innerHTML`

Comment: Can you please provide `<form></form>` part and controller. Also please tell us what you expect to get in controller and what program does.

Comment: I have Updated me code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yep, that fix that ,thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `labelvar` is an `input` element you need to set its `value`, not its `innerHTML`. Try this:

```
labelvar.value = latitude + longitude;
```